# How can I use zip(), python

Tags: python

For example, I have these variables

```
a = [1,2]
b = [3,4]
```

If I use function `zip()` for it, the result will be:

```
[(1, 3), (2, 4)]
```

But I have this list:

```
a = [[1,2], [3,4]]
```

And, I need to get the same as in the first result: `[(1, 3), (2, 4)]`. But, when I do:

```
zip(a)
```

I get:

```
[([1, 2],), ([3, 4],)]
```

What must I do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) expects multiple iterables, so if you pass a *single* list of lists as parameter, the sublists are just wrapped into tuples with one element each.

You have to use `*` to unpack the list when you pass it to `zip`. This way, you effectively pass *two* lists, instead of *one* list of lists:

```
>>> a = [[1,2], [3,4]]
>>> zip(*a)
[(1, 3), (2, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call zip differently:

```
a = [[1,2], [3,4]]
zip(a[0], a[1])
```

Comment: I know about it - but if in program don't know the exact numbers of items...?

Comment: Yeah that's a problem. Of course you could loop through the list but it's simpler to just use tobias_k's solution.